# OpenERP sever error when installing a new module (windows 7 )

Tags: python, odoo

i got a problem after creating a new module in Openerp 7.0 using Windows 7 .. when i go to install the new module i get this error "OpenERP Server Error"

```
OpenERP Server Error Client Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP 7.0-20140227-01259\Server\server\openerp\addons\web\session.py", line 89, 
    in send File "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP 7.0-20140227-001259\Server\server\.\openerp\netsvc.py", line 292, 
    in dispatch_rpc File "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP 7.0-20140227-001259\Server\server\openerp\addons\student_init_.py", line 1, 
    in <module> ImportError: No module named py
```

Comment: Will you please provide server error traceback ?

Comment: sure ... and thanks for reply 
OpenERP Server Error
Client Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP 7.0-20140227-001259\Server\server\openerp\addons\web\session.py", line 89, in send
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP 7.0-20140227-001259\Server\server\.\openerp\netsvc.py", line 292, in dispatch_rpc
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP 7.0-20140227-001259\Server\server\openerp\addons\student\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named py

Comment: there might be some problem in your code. Will you please share sample of code?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you are doing;

```
import my_module.py
```

rather than

```
import my_module
```

As in java, python using dots to break up package names so it thinks you want to import a module called "py" from a package called "my_module".  Think of it as

```
from my_module import py
```

whereas it should be (assuming this is the problem)

```
import my_module
```